# painting process for outside wrought iron

Tags: painting

I have just purchased new wrought iron rockers for my front porch.  They will get morning sun so sun probably is not an issue.  I want to add color to the rockers.  What do you suggest?  I'm sure something is needed to prevent rust.  Not sure what to do.  Thanks, Rhonda.

Comment: Somewhat related: [How to strip paint off cast iron?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/49480/how-to-strip-paint-off-cast-iron).

Answer (score 1):

If they are new, then they are not wrought iron. Wrought iron doesn't rust. Nobody has made wrought iron in almost 80 years.

I assume the rockers are made out of mild steel. There are special acrylic-based paints for outdoor steel. You have to use a metal primer.

Comment: "Wrought iron" is more of a style than an actual material nowadays.

Comment: @NickT you don't paint "styles", you paint materials.

Comment: Is an impressionistic painting a style or material?